# Error When Generating INSERT Statements for Geometry Field SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, geometry

I am populating a column of linestrings from a list of points in sql with which I use to create insert statements to populate an ID and a geometry field in a table.  This creates a temporary dataset using "with as" clauses, resulting in something like this:

CLEAN_WKT

```
ID  WKT_LINE
1   'LINESTRING(56.750011 -168.150044, 56.833377 -168.083310)'
2   'LINESTRING(54.766722 -165.050055, 54.766788 -165.083311)'
3   'LINESTRING(56.683333 -170.066766, 56.866799 -170.300012)'

   INSERT INTO TEMP(ID, GEOM) 
    SELECT ID, geometry::STGeomFromText(WKT_LINE, 0) FROM CLEAN_WKT;
```

This returns the error:  The label 'LINESTRING(56.75000 in the input well-known text (WKT) is not valid.

I can confirm that the linestring is created correctly, since I am able to print the resulting statement and execute it successfully.

Resulting SQL statement:

```
geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(56.750011 -168.150022, 56.833333 -168.083322)',0)
```

Manually created insert statement from generated SQL (see above).

```
INSERT INTO TEMP(ID, GEOM)
SELECT '1',geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(56.750011 -168.150022, 56.833333 -168.083322)', 0);
```

Anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Are the points on your line supposed to show lat/longs? If so, wouldn't it be (-168 56)?

Comment: You're right, they are reversed but since it is a geometry field instead of geography, it shouldn't cause the insert to fail.  Just for kicks, I corrected the order and still get the same error. If that had been the problem the manual insert of the generated WKT would have caught it.